How can a social norm that discussions about faith are an intimate topic survive the existence of proactive religions?
In this culture the question is about, the prevalent view is that discussing or visually displaying your faith is seen as uncomfortable behavior - roughly the same as just starting blabbering in public about the specific details of your health issues can be seen in ours. You are supposed to talk about your beliefs, if ever, behind closed doors, in private, with people you're close to.
However, religion is, essentially, a complex of memes. A successful religion that survives the competition of ideas is the one that's most viral - the one that can take root in the minds of the greatest amount of people. In this case, it seems like whatever culture proposes being covert about your religious beliefs will inevitably lose ground to a culture that doesn't have a problem with trying to convince as many as you can to adopt your beliefs (IRL example: Christianity, being (in)famous for aggressively preaching and leaving missionaries wherever it can, which resulted in them being the biggest religion on the planet, and the second biggest religion basically follows the same formula of expansion). It will be viewed as indecent and rude at first, but by the sheer fact that you're talking about your religion and others are not, you will constantly hold the spotlight (and therefore, the minds of others). "there's no such thing as bad PR" and such.
Can this be prevented without making society oppressive (enforcing the "nobody talks about their beliefs publicly" with violence and discrimination)? Can "private religion" social expectations be made competitive?

Ugh, discussions about religious faith are an intimate topic here in Europe. We do not talk with strangers about our religious faith, if any. We are strongly embarassed when American Mormons attempt to initiate such conversations. A European politician who would find themselves blabbering about God on stage in the manner of some American politicians would find themselves unemployed quite quickly, and his general practitioner would schedule a routine purely precautionary psychological evaluation. We have survived very well, thank you so much for asking.

@AlexP - So, I know what you are saying (I am originally English) - but there are Churches, Billboards, The occassional Street Preacher (or Imam...) The Jehovahs Witnesses are still door-knocking - all of which is quite 'out in the open'

@TheDemonLord: There are churches, and a few religious feast days gather huge crowds. Not really different from any other traditional festival. Yes, one does encounter the occasional madman preaching in the street. But, the question is, does it have any noticeable effect on the majority of the people? (And while I don't know about England, here in Romania Mormons and JWs seem to have largely given up; I haven't met such for years.)

I want to be sure I understand the question: you want a diverse religious experience in your world, but you also want social mores prohibiting its public discussion? If I've got that right, how long do you expect this situation to last and specifically what do you consider an undesirable means of expression? Nothing important in people's lives remains undiscussed for very long. Consider the European wars of religion.

Like @AlexP says: welcome to Europe. Flaunting your political and religious affiliations — openly and gratuitously — is a distinctly American affair (and a few other parts of the world as well). Here in Europe, matters of opinion and taste are not flaunted; you keep them to yourself. Because in Europe, opinions are like buttocks: everyone has them, meaning you are not special for having them, and no one wants yours shoved in their face before any consent is given. Also we do not operate on the Adversarial System meaning there is no need to advance/promote your position all the time.

Over here in Sweden, open proselytising as exceedingly rare. JW may have the occasional stand near some major train station, but they are very quiet and never approache anyone. Door-knocking LDS come about once per decade. Once I saw a proselytiser, I believe from the West Indies, walking up and down aisle on the regional train, trying to proclaim the "Good News"; the train chief came on the Tannoy, all embarrassed, saying "Yeah, we know about that guy, but we cannot do anything about him, sorry. Just leave him be". So, the society you are asking for is Europe, the Nordics in particular.

" without making society oppressive (enforcing the "nobody talks about their beliefs publicly" with violence and discrimination)?" What is stopping people from doing something they want to do, if no opposing force exists in your narrative? There's only three solutions: it happens, it gets opposed (through escalated layers of enforcement), or no one is wanting to do so in the first place. Your core assertion dismisses the third option, your explicit question excludes the second, so the only remaining outcome left is that it happens.

@AlexP I can tell you that as a former LDS missionary (more than 15 years ago), initiating the conversation is awkward, too. The goal is to get to the private setting, and there simply end up not being that many good alternatives to do that that one can spend their time on. Actually, I think today missionaries are much more active on social media than they used to be in my time. Door-knocking is, imo, the absolute last resort if you have nothing else to do. I consider just walking around town speaking to random people more successfull (even though that really isn't very effective either).

Sex is generally a very private affair and not talked about openly, yet everyone knows where the red light district is
Whether it is a legal red light district or not or even a shunned activity, there are still services that are being advertised.
And herein lies the answer. If direct proselytizing is not allowed, the cunning practitioners will use bait tactics to get people into a setting in which it is acceptable to talk about religion.
To continue using the example of Sex - there are many ladies who post shorts on YouTube, with a little bit of titilation. Scantily clad, braless, suggestive poses etc. And sure enough there will be a link in their bio to a website that contains all their social media links - including the inevitable one for paid adult content.
If you consider YTs ToS to be your societal norm - you can't directly post adult content or direct links to adult content on YT, this is like you can't openly display or discuss your religion.
So, instead, you have something that might entice the type of person who is looking for religion, to go from a public setting, to a private setting (like a link to an BonelyCans) where further discussion can happen.

Excellent analogy. In addition, just like it is ok to discuss sexual matters with your physician or therapist, schools have sex-ed classes and parents teach their children about the birds and the bees - In OP's society there may be professions, places or types of relationships where discussing matters of faith isn't taboo (at least in a certain, well bound way).

Just what I would have answered, only you have done it more succinctly. +1.

Yes this social expectation can be made competitive on the terms that you described if it offers a secular replacement which meets religious needs. We know this because it is happening in our own world right now. Examples include movements such as communism, scientism, or even to some extent the Olympic movement: all of them hold that the world will be made a better place if everyone just does certain right things to make it so, and are essentially advocating an utopia of some form, just an Earthly one instead of otherworldly. All of them hold themselves more important than religion, and are in some cases actively opposed to it. And as we can see, they are at the very least competitive enough to continue to exist in the presence of religions.

Freedom of Religion makes private faith more selectively fit
Private Faith survives better in multi-faith cultures. When you live in a one denomination town, there is a lot of advantages in belonging to that denomination.  If I'm a Fooist and you are probably a Fooist, then talking about being a Fooist is a good way to garner favor from someone in more cases than not.  This can lead to better employment opportunities, more access to charity when needed, more favors, etc.  However, if you live in a town with 10 common denominations, then discussing what religion you belong to will more often than not backfire on your social status.  If your Barist boss finds out that you are a Fooist, then you might get passed over for the next promotion.  If a Widgetist run charity finds out you are Fooist, they might not give you handouts when you are between jobs.  And if you talk about being a Fooist amongst your friends, 9/10ths of them will turn on you (or atleast devalue how they treat you) leaving you more isolated and poorly connected.
In this context, the best path towards success in society is in NOT discussing your faith; so, the only people who talk openly about it fall to the bottom echelons of society.  So, while your vocally active religion might get the most exposure, it means that it will only thrive as a "poor man's church".  Poor socio-economic and political standing will mean that your open religion will also become associated with all the same problems that poorer demographics often face.  Instead of rising up to become a powerful church, they will be seen as  the gypsies, tramps and thieves of your society leading to a bad public image and more people wanting to avoid your denomination.
Christianity actually thrived because of Theocratic Politics
Christianity did not start off as an openly practiced religion that spits out tons of missionaries and public speakers.  Between 64-313 CE it was considered a mystery religion. You had to be born into the church or invited into by someone who deeply trusts you.  It's members were sworn to secrecy, and open preaching was a good way to lose not just your social status, but your very life.  In 313 CE, it became legal to openly practice christianity, but missionary work was still not common.
What really pulled Christianity out of the shadows though was when Emperor Theodosius issued the Edict of Thessalonica in 380 CE making Nicene Christianity the official religion of the Roman Empire and deemed all other religions heretical. So it was actually the involvement of a small handful of secular rulers forcing a one religion policy in the largest and most powerful empire in the world that really cemented Christianity's power, not its openness.  From that point on, the Roman Empire was essentially a theocracy which means that openly talking about being a Nicene Christian became a good way to rise in political and economic power, and openly talking about any other faith was a good way to lose it.
As Christianity continued from that point, majority power became an important anchor for the church, but it did not actually spread much beyond the original boundaries of the Roman Empire for another 1000 years.  Just like Emperor Theodosius used religion to cement his political power; so too did medieval rulers.  Early missionaries were successful because they did not need to survive on their own merit.  They were funded by powerful and wealthy patrons in foreign theocratic places, and often appealed not to the people of foreign lands, but the rulers, and it was a spread of theocratic policy that really drove out the diversity of religions and made it advantageous to openly discuss faith: as long as you were a Roman Catholic.
How Faith is Again Becoming Taboo
That said, Theocracies are unsustainable.  It takes force and oppression to establish and maintain a Theocracy; so, sooner or later, you they all face either a gradual weakening or open rebellion.  When Theocracies wain, they tend to be replaced by cultures that advocate a Freedom of Religion policy.
Ever since the Protestant Reformation, Christianity has splintered over and over again so that what was once just a small handful of State Sponsored Creeds has devolved into about 45,000 denominations worldwide. Without the backing of the State, religion naturally diversifies and openly discussing your faith becomes worse for your social standing. So as long as your nation protects Freedom of Religion, the most powerful religions will tend to be the ones that practice in private.

Religion must be developed and taught some way.
A religion, or culture, or philosophy, or science, or language, etc., cannot long survive if it can't be communicated or taught in some way.  So, how intimate is "intimate"?  If it cannot be spoken of outside of the family, it cannot ever spread to more than one family.  If it can only be spoken of between people who are already converted, then it cannot survive at all.  So, I suspect you will have to get a better idea of what the rules are in your fictional culture.
It could be that there are certain expected ways of discussing religion, for example, that this is something adult men discuss over "pipes and pints" at the neighborhood public house, and that such discussions rarely involve women and children -- fathers would therefore be the teachers of their own families in matters of religion, and little would be said out in public during the daytime.  This would be a very reserved and philosophical society that still gets the job done (of developing and communicating religious ideas).
Another approach is that religion is rooted in tradition in such a way that missionaries cannot crack it.  I recently read about how the Spanish missionaries had trouble introducing Christianity to the mesoamerican Nahuatl people (Aztecs). The Nahuatl communicated their religious views through traditional song-poems passed down through the culture, and measured any new ideas against that tradition.  When the missionaries tried to introduce Christianity they made the mistake of saying "this is something your ancestors didn't know about" and trying to teach in the form of lectures.  This caused their hearers to simply shut their ears to it.
Religious discussion could be channeled in some way that favors "private" transmission.
I think your challenge is to design a society such that the usual techniques of mass evangelization do not hit home with the intended audience, but that religion is discussed, developed, and transmitted in some way that favors "viral" transmission.  Here are some ideas:

In a stuffy, stoic culture where religion is treated as a philosophical matter among educated men, then preaching or pamphlets aimed at the uneducated masses, women, and children, would be considered obnoxious and probably turn the men against their ideas.

In a traditional culture where the people are deeply interested in history, genealogy, ancestral beliefs, etc., then they'll be uninterested in anything that seems "new" or comes from outside, so foreign missionaries as well as domestic innovators will not find friendly audiences.

In a decadent culture like the late Roman Empire, maybe people are fascinated by "mystery" religions.  They may be particularly attracted to being invited to share a secret, only taught behind closed doors.  As soon as that belief becomes "mainstream" they'll lose interest in it.


You can probably think of other such scenarios.  One other situation that comes to mind is that religion might spread through private interactions among a conquered or oppressed people.  In that case they would communicate it privately not because of "manners" but because of the danger of being persecuted for their belief.  In this case, the very fact that they're willing to brave the danger of martyrdom to teach others, is an argument for the veracity of the teaching.

Wow. This is the oversimplification of the decade:

However, religion is, essentially, a complex of memes.

This is in essence incorrect. Religion is a cultural phenomenon deeply intertwined with local customs, politics, language, and most importantly death. To distill it to simple slogans that thrive on popularity is to truly lose the substance of the matter.
Karl Marx famously wrote Religion is the Opiate of the people. Therein lies your answer as well. The full passage is an explanation of why religion exists rather than the scathing remark most people take it to be.
Religion is the only medicine for despair. Marx follows that as long as there is strife, hopelessness, and death in this world, so too will we need religion. Regardless of the specific cannons of your religions, they will thrive simply because it is a natural condition of humanity to create theology to explain the unexplainable.

> To distill it to simple slogans that thrive on popularity is to truly lose the substance of the matter.
A meme is not a "slogan", a meme is, basically, an idea. I'm talking about the original definition of a meme, not about the modern internet term for funny viral pictures (Now THAT's an oversimplification that truly loses the substance of the matter). Complexity may vary, but it doesn't change the fact that it does not physically exist outside our consciousnesses.

@DarthBiomech You are missing the point. The fear we all share of the dark. The sadness we feel when a loved one is gone. These are not memetic. They were not given to us by copying others. These emotions are the root of religion. The lore and meanings we attach to things, sure. But if you don't understand why religions exist, how could you hope to build a believable world with your parameters?
